# How do I highlight the marker on the map when click on matching carousel corresponding to the marker to the map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, slick.js, datamaps

Say the first carousel slide is Los Angeles California and when click on it, the red dot marker on the map will change its color to like blue on Los Angeles, CA coordinate. When click on the 2nd slide the 1st highlighted marker will back to default red and the new marker will be highlighted to blue.

**I am not sure how to go about connecting these two using Vanilla JS.**
If logic connects, I can easily change the red dot color using CSS.

[image: Example what I am going for]

I am using DataMaps to render the USA map with coordinates of certain cities from a JSON file and slick-carousel for the bottom carousel.

JSON

```
[
    {
        "city": "Madison",
        "state": "WI",
        "latitude": 43.07199845990384,
        "longitude": -89.40813691528471
    },
    {
        "city": "Columbus",
        "state": "OH",
        "latitude": 40.00178899021552,
        "longitude": -83.01964928313465
    }
]
```

Here I fetch the json file, initialization of DataMaps and logic for populate json objects into carousel HTMLs.

```
// Get JSON data
fetch('assets/json/cities.json')
  .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (data) {
      appendData(data);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
      console.log('error: ' + err);
  });

var map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById("map"),
  responsive: true,
  height: null,
  width: null,
  scope: 'usa',
  geographyConfig: { // USA map color
    popupOnHover: false,
    highlightOnHover: false,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderOpacity: 0.6,
    borderColor: '#ffffff'
  },
  bubblesConfig: { // USA city popup color
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderOpacity: 1,
    borderColor: '#c5002e',
    popupOnHover: true,
    radius: null,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    animate: true,
    highlightOnHover: true,
    highlightFillColor: '#c5002e', //  hover dot color
    highlightBorderColor: '#c5002e',
    highlightBorderWidth: 1,
    highlightBorderOpacity: 1,
    highlightFillOpacity: 0.75,
    exitDelay: 100,
    key: JSON.stringify,
    popupTemplate: function(geography, data) {
      return '<div class="hoverinfo">' + data.name + '</div>';
    },
  },
    fills: {
      defaultFill: '#3a3a3a', // map color
      city: '#c5002e' //  dot color
  }
});

// Responsive map
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  map.resize();
});

// Loop to grab all json objects and render them in the page
function appendData(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var city = (data[i].city),
        state = (data[i].state),

    const locations = document.createElement("div");

    // Add html
    locations.innerHTML = `
      <div class="city__locations-slide">
        <div class="city__locations-slide-inner">
          <p class="">${city} ${state}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;

    document.querySelector(".city__locations").append(locations)

  }
```

Slick-carousel code

```
//initilize city locations slick carousel
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".city__locations").slick({
    dots: true,
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="city__locations-prev-button"/>',
    nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="city__locations-next-button"/>',
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 640,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-24">
      <div id="map-location" class="push--40 city__locations"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is initial example in [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/vomekaq/edit?html,js,output).

If this all work out, there is another date feature I would like to implement it. When the current date is bigger/equal to the date in the json date object, the red dot marker will also be highlighted it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can add some data attributes to the

```js
return '<div data-unique-identifier class="hoverinfo">' + data.name + '</div>';
```

then with the carousel divs wire up a mouse over event and then you can use the data attributes to match the div to the corresponding icon. With the date you can again add a custom CSS class in the above line to create a highlight a bit like so:

```js
return '<div data-unique-identifier class="' + new Date(data.someDate) === new Date('Jul 12 2011') ? highlight : hoverinfo + '">' + data.name + '</div>';
```

It's hard to help without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

I hope this helps

Comment: I have created an initial example in [jsbin](https://output.jsbin.com/vomekaq).
 
Thanks for the help Patrick. I am thinking to add an attribute like data-id to both the map and the carousel so if I click the carousel slide, the mouseevent click with find the same data-id and maybe the map markers will change the color with modify CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a glow effect, the glow is a bit much, CSS isn't my strong suit but should do what you wanted and you can tweak the CSS. I couldn't find a way to override the CSS on the map dots, so I used a div that is positioned in the create the glow effect

```js
// Init USA map
var map = new Datamap({
  element: document.getElementById("map"),
  responsive: true,
  height: null,
  width: null,
  scope: 'usa',
  geographyConfig: { // USA map color
    popupOnHover: false,
    highlightOnHover: false,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderOpacity: 0.6,
    borderColor: '#ffffff'
  },
  bubblesConfig: { // USA city popup color
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderOpacity: 1,
    borderColor: '#c5002e',
    popupOnHover: true,
    radius: null,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    animate: true,
    highlightOnHover: true,
    highlightFillColor: '#c5002e', //  hover dot color
    highlightBorderColor: '#c5002e',
    highlightBorderWidth: 1,
    highlightBorderOpacity: 1,
    highlightFillOpacity: 0.75,
    exitDelay: 100,
    key: JSON.stringify,
    popupTemplate: function(geography, data) {
      return '<div class="hoverinfo">' + data.name + '</div>';
    },
  },
  fills: {
    defaultFill: '#3a3a3a', // map color
    city: '#c5002e' //  dot color
  }
});

// Responsive map
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  map.resize();
});

// City popup
map.bubbles([{
    radius: 10,
    fillKey: 'city',
    name: 'Madison, WI',
    cityId: "1",
    latitude: 43.07199845990384,
    longitude: -89.40813691528471
  },
  {
    radius: 10,
    fillKey: 'city',
    name: 'Columbus, OH',
    cityId: "2",
    latitude: 40.00178899021552,
    longitude: -83.01964928313465
  },
  {
    radius: 10,
    fillKey: 'city',
    name: 'Gainesville, FL',
    cityId: "3",
    latitude: 29.645407365499,
    longitude: -82.348610942268
  },
  {
    radius: 10,
    fillKey: 'city',
    name: 'Chestnut Hill, MA',
    cityId: "4",
    latitude: 42.335294607839636,
    longitude: -71.16643600759312
  }
]);


//initilize city locations slick carousel
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".city__locations").slick({
    dots: true,
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="city__locations-prev-button"/>',
    nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="city__locations-next-button"/>',
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 640,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  $(".city__locations-slide").each(function() {
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
      const location = $(this)
        .children(".city__locations__locations-slide-inner")
        .children("p").html()
      const mapMatch = $(".datamaps-bubble").filter(function() {
        return $(this).data("info").name === location
      })
      $(".glow").css({
        top: mapMatch.position().top + 'px',
        left: mapMatch.position().left + 'px',
      }).show();
    }).mouseout(function() {
      $(".glow").hide();
    })
  })
});
```

```css
.glow {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px 30px #fff, 0 0 100px 60px #f0f, 0 0 140px 90px #0ff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>USA Map with carousel</title>
  <style>
    .city__locations-slide {
      background-color: lightgrey;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    
    .city__locations-prev-button {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 30%;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      z-index: 111;
    }
    
    .city__locations-next-button {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 30%;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      z-index: 111;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="columns small-24">
        <div id="map" class="" style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 1);"></div>
        <div id="map-location" class="push--40 city__locations">
          <div class="city__locations-slide">
            <div class="city__locations__locations-slide-inner">
              <p>Madison, WI</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="city__locations-slide">
            <div class="city__locations__locations-slide-inner">
              <p>Columbus, OH</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="city__locations-slide">
            <div class="city__locations__locations-slide-inner">
              <p>Gainesville, FL</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="city__locations-slide">
            <div class="city__locations__locations-slide-inner">
              <p>Chestnut Hill, MA</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="glow" class="glow">

  </div>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datamaps/0.5.8/datamaps.usa.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/PatrickHume/e1m7quj6/90/

I hope this helps ?

Comment: Thanks Patrick. This definitely helped. I am also exploring an opposite way. Meaning instead of clicking on the slide, I click the map marker and the slide that correspond to the marker highlighted. Probably I can expand on the code you provided.

Comment: I found a great example exactly what I am looking for. [Map with carousel](https://codespacing.com/progress-map-demos/layouts/map-up-carousel-down/). Pretty cool the way whoever did it and looking at the codes, it seems pretty complicated.

Comment: well glad you find something that will work for you,  I hope if nothing else my answer was somewhat helpful ;)

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I was testing in my local (not in jsbin) it but a weird bug came up. I was clicking it and the coordinate for top pixel is not correct. The CSS is set to top: 2723.87px & left: 969.688px. The top pixel in thousand doesn't seems correct. Did I not sat position relative somewhere? It also gave me an error message in the chrome console. It says (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top'))

Comment: I assume you mean my version not the one from the link you posted? if so can you download https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rsguu1?file=index.html (click the small cloud image next where it says "project" left, top hand side of the page, it will say download when you hoer over it) that give you the example to run on your desktop (need to extract it from zip file, see if you have the same issue there?